# Embed a GIF onto an existing PNG file

Tags: png, gif

H just created a banner in PNG format and I'd like to render a GIF in the center. So the output would be a GIF file where the center moves and the rest of the PNG is made into static frames. I've only done basic things in photoshop and never worked with gif files. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image formats are all or nothing. You can not mix and match formats within the same image.

Your **entire** image must be either a gif or a png, it can't be both.

The only way to use multiple formats is to use multiple images. If feasible, you could code html so that a png sits on either side of a gif, but you'll need 3 images.

Comment: I thought about this too, 3 images, I guess thats the only way? There's no way to re-render the new gif with all the content?

Comment: You can open the gif, change the canvas size, and add the content from the PNG on either side (make certain it shows in every frame). Then resave as gif. This will, of course, increase the file size of the gif.

Comment: Ah yea, and I guess it would also take some time to pull off. Well thanks for the help.